# Migrate mysql db from XAMPP to WAMP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, wamp

I built a sql database using phpmyadmin in xampp. I'm now switching to wamp. To transfer the db I copied the db files from xampp, located in xampp//... mysql/data// and pasted them to the wamp//... mysql/data//. However, the data tables do not appear when I run phpmyadmin from wamp.

I would export the databases from the xampp-phpmyadmin directly into wamp-phpmyadmin, but I've uninstalled xampp and no longer have the source files, other than what was located in xampp//... mysql/data//.

Am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the recommended way to copy database files. It may work (which is why you sometimes see people recommending it), it may sort of work (requiring you to reset permissions), or it may completely fail to copy any of your data over. A much more robust means to transfer the database is to do an SQL export from the old server then import it to the new server. Since you got rid of the old installation, we'll move past that point quickly, but to be clear there are no promises it will work.

Based on what you've already done, my first guess is that your user doesn't have permission on the new database. Are you logged in as the root user or another user with administrative privileges?

When you say you copied the db files, do you mean you copied the folder (with the same or similar name as your database) and all files inside that folder? Please check the file system permissions of that folder and the files within to make sure they match the permissions and owner/group of the other MySQL data files. Do you know what table type the tables were?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I needed to login as the root user with admin. The db successfully migrated.

Comment: Excellent! The reason for this is that the permissions are stored in the `mysql` database, which you didn't copy (nor is generally recommended to copy); now you can go ahead and recreate the proper permissions for your user on that database.

Answer (score 2):

The folder with the name of your database, lets call it `mydatabase` should be copied to `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\data\mydatabase`

**Dont copy any other folders, only the ones with the names of the databases you actually created yourself.**

If the MySQL version is the same as the one you used to create the database this should work just fine. It may work if the versions differ by a little, but if the versions are very different it probably wont work.